# A morphism of semi-stable vector bundle of degree $0$ is of constant rank?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be semistable vector bundles of degree $0$ over a smooth projective curve $X$. How does one prove that any $f\in Hom(V_1,V_2)$ has constant rank? That is the rank of the linear maps $f_x:(V_1)_x\rightarrow (V_2)_x$ doesn't change with respect to $x\in X$.

Answer (score 2):

In the title you say degree 0, in the body you don't. Without that assumption, the answer is no.

Assuming degree 0, let $f:V_1\to V_2$ be such a map and let $W=f(V_1)$. Semistability says that $\deg W\leq 0$ and then since the kernel of $f$ also has degree less than or equal to zero, we see that both must be degree 0. If $W$ is not a subbundle, then its saturation in $V_2$ will have positive degree, which is not possible, so $W$ is a subbundle and that precisely says the map has constant rank.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the degree 0 part. I have added it in the main body. I don't know why ker is a sub-bundle implies the morphism has constant rank. I have seen a theorem the other way- "If a morphism is of constant rank then the kernel and the image is a sub-bundle". (Le Poteir Proposition 1.7.2)

Comment: I said $W=f(V_1)$ is a subbundle of $V_2$ and then the rank is constant.

Comment: I don't follow your argument. Unless, you prove $W=f(V_1)$ is a sub-bundle of $V_2$, $deg(W)$ doesn't makes sense.

Comment: By saturation do you mean the sub-bundle generated by $W$?

Comment: Degree makes sense for any coherent sheaf. Yes, saturation means the subbundle generated by $W$.

Comment: Why does the saturation must have positive degree?

Comment: If $W\subset G$ are bundles with $G/W$ supported on a finite set of points, then $\deg G\geq \deg W$ and this inequality is strict if $G/W\neq 0$.